# GitLab runner on Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

So we're trying to deploy a GitLab runner on Heroku. First we tried to create a docker image but that failed as we couldn't get docker to run on our Windows machines (had to use Docker Toolbox which wouldn't work...). Then we tried to clone the GitLab runner repo and simply push it to Heroku but then this happens:

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to pum-gitlab-runner.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/pum-gitlab-runner.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pum-gitlab-runner.git'
```

Anyone got a clue as to how we can accomplish this?

Comment: did you get any solutions on this?

Comment: Nope, and herokus support weren’t of any help either. We switched to digital ocean instead.